# 1984: Ignorance is?

Tags: word-choice, word-phrases

In Orwell's *1984*, that I actually read circa 1984, is back among the best sellers on Amazon.  Central to the story is the iconic three lines:

> “War is peace.”
>
> “Freedom is slavery.”
>
> “Ignorance is strength.”

Why was it not ignorance is knowledge or weakness is strength?

Comment: Isn't this a question for the author?

Comment: Because what you don´t know cannot hurt you? And that makes you invincible. You may want to post this on Literature.SE, when it exits beta.

Comment: Can't it be posted there now, if Pete joins? http://literature.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be mainly about literary aspects of word choice.

Answer (score 1):

Ignorance - whether honest lack-of-knowledge or intentionally adopted and performed - is the foundation of 1984's society. Without the general public either being ignorant or affecting an attitude of pretended ignorance, the society would have been less likely to progress to that point unless the populace really didn't resist. By existing in ignorance of the true state of world events, the populace cedes control to the powerful who are shaping events to their liking.

Oceania, as a society, has no love for weakness. Yes, "Ignorance is knowledge" would fit, as it is the same sort of self-contradicting statement as the previous two. But in-universe, the purpose of the three statements (as I recall) is to destroy the meaningfulness of objection to the negative half of each pair, and on the other hand, destroy the desire for the positive half of the pairs by an absurd equivalency. These slogans are a tool for influence and control.  So perhaps those who penned these lines considered that their populace would find strength more desirable than knowledge, and therefore would be more moved by the statement.

Out of universe, national strength is a popular theme in politics, and (while I don't know firsthand) I would suspect it was a popular theme in the sorts of political environments Orwell was satirizing.